# Showing ProgressDialog only once in a recursive AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

In the Java code I have executed an AsyncTask class and with the returned result I have done a recursive call to itself in the onPostexecute method. Example:

MainActivity.java

```
public void button_clicked(){
  UploadAsync send_data = new UploadAsync(MainActivity.this);
  send_data.execute("send first data", user_data, file_path);
}
```

UploadAsync.java

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  String task = params[0];
  if(task.equals("send first data"){
    String user_data = params[1];
    String file_path = params[2];

    //send in the user_data to a php file

  }else if(task.equals("send file"){
    String file_path = params[1];

    //send the file_path to another php file

  }
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
 ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending", "Please wait");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  if(result.equals("data sent"){
    UploadAsync send_data = new UploadAsync(context);
    send_data.execute("send file", file_path);
  }else{
    //show error
  }

  pd.dismiss();
}
```

The code above is only an example made. Now the thing is, implementing this example will run the progress dialog twice. I have tried many ways to only show the progress dialog once while the AsyncTask is sending the user data and the file path but I'm not succeeding. Is there any suggestions on how to implement this correctly?

Comment: use publishupdate method inside doinbackground and use onprogressupdate method to show it in dialog https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar

Answer (score 0):

Can't you call `pd.dismiss()` and dismiss `ProgressDialog` for the current `UploadAsync` before executing new `UploadAsync`?

Comment: Indeed I can. However, that is the problem I am facing. The PD is showing twice, meaning the user can see that the PD is dismissed and another one is starting right after it. And that is what I want to prevent. So what I'm trying to do basically is to only have one PD show up when the two AsyncTask objects are executing.

Comment: Oh, then can't you do all your operation inside `doInBackground` without executing new `UploadAsync`? I mean first send user data, if it was successful, do not return "data sent" here, instead send file and if sending file is successful too, now return "data sent" from `doInBackground` and dismiss `ProgressDialog` inside `onPostExecute` :)

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute first, dismiss the dialog and then start new asynctask like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

  pd.dismiss();

  if(result.equals("data sent"){
    UploadAsync send_data = new UploadAsync(context);
    send_data.execute("send file", file_path);
  }else{
    //show error
  }

}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let `ProgressDialog` as global data .

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // show the ProgressDialog
    if (pd == null) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Sending", "Please wait");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result.equals("data sent") {
        UploadAsync send_data = new UploadAsync(context);
        send_data.execute("send file", file_path);
    }else{
        //show error
    }
    // edited here ,make the ProgressDialog dismiss
    if (pd.isShowing() && pd != null) {
        pd.dismiss();
        pd = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case use callback mechanism between the async task and the caller(here, `MainActivity`).

Implement as I explained below.

- Define an `interface` with `showProgressDiaglog()` and
  `DismissProgressDialog()` methods.
- `MainActivity` implements this interface and implements the two
  methods to show and dismiss progress dialog respectively.
- Define `setter method` in your `AsyncTask` class and call this setter
  method from the `MainActivity` by passing `this`(this refers to
  MainActivity) after `creating the AsyncTask instance and before
  calling execute method.` store the passed interface implementation in
  the AsyncTask class as an instance variable.
- Modify AsyncTask constructor to pass the task type instead of passing
  in the execute method and store this task type in the AsyncTask as an
  instance variable.
- Now from within the AsyncTask constructor, in `onPreExecute()`
  method, call `showProgressDialog()` method based on the task type.
  and in `onPostEecute()` method call `dismissProgressDialog()`
  depending on the task type.